Do Stirling permutations have Inverses, Cycles, or RSK Analogues?
I am interested in Stirling permutations, introduced by Gessel and Stanley
(cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_permutation),
and I am wondering whether Stirling permutations share fundamental properties similar to those of ordinary permutations. Specifically:

The set of ordinary permutations of size $n$ forms the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$. Does the set of Stirling permutations of size $n$
form some kind of group? If so, what is the group operation, and how is the "inverse" of a Stirling permutation defined?
Ordinary permutations can be decomposed into disjoint cycles. The Stirling number of the first kind counts the number of ordinary permutations of size $n$ with $k$ cycles. For Stirling permutations, is there an analogous notion of "cycles"? If so, can we define a Stirling-number-like statistic for Stirling permutations?
Using the Robinson-Schensted (RS) algorithm for ordinary permutations, we can derive the well-known representation-theoretical formula:
\begin{align}
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(f^\lambda)^2=n!.
\end{align}
Is there an analogue of the RS algorithm for Stirling permutations that could lead to a similar formula, such as:
\begin{align}
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(\rm{some\ kind\ of\ tableau})^2=(2n-1)!!?
\end{align}
I am aware that formulas of this type can be derived using oscillating tableaux
(cf. https://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/opapers/s20delest.pdf),
but it seems unrelated to the specific context of Stirling permutations.

Thanks to everyone for viewing or help.
